# Retrofit: Post raw text "user={"key1": "value1", etc.}?

Tags: java, android, json, text, retrofit

So I am pretty new on that library (Retrofit) and actually I am stucked on an atypical case.

I have an API where I try to register (sign up) a new user to it, to test it I use "DHC Rest Client" on Chrome. It works when I send this (see below):

**Header:**

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Body (text)**

user={"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", etc.}

So my plan is to make the same thing on Android ! I have created an interface (see below):

Interface

```
interface RestRegister{
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @POST("/api/register")
    void postRegister(@Body String user, Callback<LoginResponse> callback);
}
```

But I always get a "Failed!" from the Callback error handler. I correctly get the correct parameters (I give it as a simple String with the correct format - "user={\"email\":\"lol@lol.us\", etc.}").

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                       .setEndpoint("http://ENDPOINT:3000/")
                                       .build();

                               RestRegister restRegister = restAdapter.create(RestRegister.class);

                               restRegister.postRegister("user={\"email\":\"lol@lol.us\",\"first_name\":\"jean\",\"last_name\":\"loop\",\"password\":\"test95test\",\"gender\":\"1\",\"birthdate\":\"1978/05/16\"}", new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {
                                       Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Created !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       Intent intent = new Intent("com.signupconfirmation");
                                       startActivity(intent);
                                   }

                                   @Override
                                   public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                       Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, query, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                       Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Failed !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   }
                               });
                           }
                       });
```

Later I would like to create a JSONObject in the right format too ;).

Waiting for your answers :) !

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? It's not easy to understand what exactly you want to accomplish and where are you having problems.

Comment: Hi Seb' ! So the API developper from my team has made a weird way of user registration. I want to make as I make on DHC Rest Client on Chrome, i.e. I want to send a raw text body with the header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded". The body will contain for example: 'user={"email": "jean.bean@msn.com", "first_name": "Jean", "last_name": "Bean", "password": "test95test", "gender": "1", "birthdate": "1978/05/16"}'. I want to do this on Android by using Retrofit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the documentation suggests:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/user/edit")
User updateUser(@Field("first_name") String first, @Field("last_name") String last);
```

In your case it would be:

```
interface RestRegister{
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/register")
    void postRegister(@Field("user") String data, Callback<LoginResponse> callback);
}
```

And then:

```
restRegister.postRegister("{\"email\":\"lol@lol.us\",\"first_name\":\"jean\",\"last_name\":\"loop\",\"password\":\"test95test\",\"gender\":\"1\",\"birthdate\":\"1978/05/16\"}", ...);
```

Comment: If I do that way It will send {"user": ""email": "lol@lol.us", "first_name": etc."} and in this case it would not work :( !

Comment: Are you sure? It shouldn't.

Comment: Let me try, I come to back to you ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                       .setEndpoint("http://ENDPOINT:3000/")
                                       .build();
```

**Should be**

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                       .setEndpoint("http://ENDPOINT:3000")
                                       .build();
```

For Example:

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
 @POST("/alert.php")
 void gettingfirsttimealert(@Field("key") String value, @Field("user_id") String user_id, Callback<JsonResponseis> cb);
```

JSON Response

```
{ "success": true,
        "details": {
    "firstname": mathan,
            "arraylist": [
                "subscribe": "subscribe"
    ]
}
}
```

POJO class should be

```
public class JsonResponseis{

   // Json response key is String
    public String success;

    //Json response key  is JSON OBJECT
    public Details details;

    public class Details {

        public String firstname;
      //json response  key is arraylist
    public List<ArrayListis> arraylist;

    }

    public class ArrayListis{
        public String subscribe;
    }
}
```

CallBack Should be

```
public Callback downloadalertcalback = new Callback() {
    String alertmediapath = "null";
    String ts;
    @Override
    public void success(Object o, Response response) {
        JsonResposeis u = (JsonResposeis ) o;
        if (u.success != null) {

            if (u.success.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                //Do here
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

    }

};
```

Comment: Hello dear friend, thanks for your answer but with the "/" at the end or not it is the same result ;) !