# Retrofit POST raw string body

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to send a POST request to a server. The body of the POST **must be in the form `jdata={"key1":"value1",...}`** along with a Content-Type header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I found a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855793/retrofit-post-raw-text-user-key1-value1-etc) question but the accepted answer is not working.

Here's what I tried -

My interface

```
public interface APIHandler {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST(URL)
    Call<ResponseBody> getdata(@Field("jdata") String jdata);
}
```

Call function

```
public void load() {
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("BASE_URL")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

// prepare call in Retrofit 2.0
APIHandler iAPI = retrofit.create(APIHandler.class);

String requestBody = "{\"id\":\"value\",\"id1\":\"value2\"}"
Call<ResponseBody> call = iAPI.getData(requestBody);

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> c, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            ResponseBody result = response.body();
            String gs = new Gson().toJson(result);
            Log.d("MainActivity", "response = " + gs + " status: " + statusCode);

        } else {
            Log.w("myApp", "Failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> c, Throwable t) {
    }
});
}
```

But I receive `response = null` and `status = 200`. What am I doing wrong? The expected response is only a string and not a JSON array.

Comment: this `{"key1":"value1",...}` is a json data. You can use gson an convert pojo to json object and then post that to server

Comment: Yes, but I need to post `jdata={"key1":"value1",...}` not `{"key1":"value1",...}`

Comment: check toString method @ http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: The argument is already a string (`requestBody`).

Comment: did you check the response via postman?

Comment: Yes, I checked using DHC and the result is as expected. If I remove the header or remove `jdata=` from the body, it returns "No Content" so both are required.

Comment: then it should work. i would check the request format again. the code looks alright

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this here so that it helps someone.

The above code is correct. As I mentioned in the last line, a **plain string** response was expected. But since it is not a JSON response, the conversion probably did not work and the response was null. The only solution I could find was to directly convert the response to string -

```
try {
        stresp = response.body().string()
        Log.d("MainActivity", "response = " + stresp + " status: " + statusCode);
    } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Handle exception
}
```

There might be a better way to handle this but that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that. I have tested this and it working fine

```
public interface APIHandler {
    @POST(URL)
    Call<ResponseBody> getdata(@Body JsonObject body);
}
```

Request body:

```
JsonObject requestBody = new JsonObject();
requestBody.addProperty("id", "value1");
requestBody.addProperty("id1", "value2");
```

Prepare call in Retrofit 2.0

```
APIHandler iAPI = retrofit.create(APIHandler.class);
```

And Call function :

```
 Call<ResponseBody> call = iAPI.getData(requestBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> c, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccess()) {
                String result = response.body().string();

                Log.d("MainActivity", "response = " + result);

            } else {
                Log.w("myApp", "Failed");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> c, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```